# How to increment progress bar through XAML animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to place a progress bar that takes 10 seconds to complete 100% progress. It should increment 10% per second. I would like a XAML approach. I know how to do that with a `DispacherTimer` or similar thing. How can I do that with XAML only?

I have some idea, but I don't know how to finish it or even if it's possible.

```
 <ProgressBar>
       <ProgressBar.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
              <BeginStoryboard>
                   <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:10"></DoubleAnimation>
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
        </ProgressBar.Triggers>
  </ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Usually progress is synchronized with ... progress. Even if you know time in advance it's worth to organize progress reporting... Have you tried to specify `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"`? If that doesn't work you can animate width of 100% full progress bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply using a `DoubleAnimation` that animates the `Value` property using linear interpolation over 10 seconds?:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100">
    <ProgressBar.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Duration="00:00:10" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ProgressBar.Triggers>
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't finding what put in "Storyboard.TargetProperty. It was simpler than I thought.